# How can i search for a specific string after an ls command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu

I am trying to make a shell script that searches the /proc directory and finds the user of the process. how am i supposed to do that? i am trying different ways with grep like

```
NUM=`egrep -ri  "$a1" /proc/ 2> error.txt ` 
echo "$NUM"
```

but nothing happen.Can someone help?

Comment: What's the value in the variable `a1`?

Comment: its the first parameter when you run the script.

Comment: @Nomik If you want to refer to the first parameter, then you'd use `$1` and not `$a1`.

Comment: i have given the value of the first parameter to the variable a1 so its the same isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` searches the contents of files. To search files owned by `someone`, try something like

```
find /proc -user someone -ls
```

Trivially, you could pipe `ls` through a filter to obtain only those lines where the third field is `someone`, as hinted at in comments;

```
ls -l | awk '$3=="someone"'
```

... but for many various reasons you should [avoid parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in general.

If you know the numeric user ID, you could do something like

```
awk '$1=="Uid" && $2==1234 { print FILENAME }' /proc[1-9]*/status
```

to obtain the file names of the processes owned by UID number 1234. Something very similar could be obtained by `find`, as in the first example. (Maybe restrict search to only numeric directory names?)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help sir..really appreciated.!
Best Regards
Kimon

Answer (score 1):

To find the userid of a process via the /proc pseudo-filesystem, grab the "Uid" line from the "status" file:

```
uid_line=`grep -e ^Uid /proc/1/status`
```

You can parse that apart into real, effective, saved set, and filesystem uids.  The second field is the real uid:

```
real_uid=`echo "$uid_line"|cut -f 2`
```

You can also convert uid into username using `getent`:

```
username=`getent passwd $real_uid|cut -d: -f 1`
```

Comment: This is very usefull. Thank you very much, but here is the question. I want to see all the processes that user "Someone" has inside proc directory and THEN do all theses stuff to get the UID. when i am in proc directory and run ls it appears on the 3rd column the name of the user and thats what i want to "save".

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure userids for processes are in /proc/PID/loginid.

Comment: i want to get some information from the status file from a specific process i choose to search.For example i want to get some information about all the process that user "Someone" has. to do that i want to know the name of the user and i can see it if i run ls -l while being on proc directory, but i cant get it right with grep..

Comment: Oh.  One way would be to filter your ls -l output.  You can use awk for that.  ls -l | awk '{print $3}' may do the trick for you.

Comment: I included a variation on this in my updated answer.